# Insert lines based on numeric value

Tags: bash, file, text, lines

how can I use bash and scripting tools to go from this file:

```
apples 2  
oranges 3  
bananas 1  
pears 2
```

to this file:

```
apples  
apples  
oranges  
oranges   
oranges  
bananas  
pears  
pears
```

I tried some awk without success

Comment: If you already tried something, you should include it in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
awk '{ for (i=0; i<$2; ++i) print $1 }' file
```

Use the value in the second column to determine the number of iterations in the `for` loop. Print the first column that many times.

Output:

```
apples
apples
oranges
oranges
oranges
bananas
pears
pears
```

Or perhaps a bit of Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[0]\n" x $F[1]' file
```

Split each line into columns using `-a` and print the first column (+ newline) as many times as the value of the second one.

Comment: Tks. Love the simplicity of the perl one.

Answer (score 2):

You can even do it in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r fruit count; do
    for ((i = 0; i < count; i++)); do
        echo "$fruit"
    done
done
```